# Unbind a request when authenticating SAML using ITofxtec

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am following this example [How to Authenticate with SAML in ASP.NET Core and C#](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/10/23/how-to-authenticate-with-saml-in-aspnet-core-and-csharp)

The `meat and potatoes` of the SAML implementation in in the route `AssertionConsumerService()`.  In it, there's the following line of code:

```
binding.Unbind(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse);
```

I have 2 questions:

1. What does `unbinding` here do and do I need to call it? I can guess based on the name unbind does some sort of cleaning up or de-initialization.
2. I am also getting an error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    System.NullReferenceException`. I couldn't really seem to capture anything else meaningful like the callstack, and all those objects `binding`, `Request`, `saml2AuthnResponse` are **non null**. But it seems like if I omit this line, then everything seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The `Unbind` method read the XML SAML 2.0 response you have received and do the validation.

You can look at the [ASP.NET Core sample](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/FoxIDs.Samples/tree/master/src/AspNetCoreOidcAuthorizationCodeSample) to see what you are doing differently and probably locate the `NullReferenceException`.